# Subclassing and Casting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I came across a strange problem today. I created a subclass of UIView and added only 1 method to the template code provided by xcode.

```
@interface FloatView : UIView {

}
- (void)floatTest:(CGFloat)x;
@end

- (void)floatTest:(CGFloat)x {
  NSLog(@"float was %f", x);
}
```

Then in my appDelegate I had code like this:

```
UIView *floatView = [[FloatView alloc] init];
[floatView floatTest:10.0f];
```

Pretty simple, right? What should this print out? I thought it would something like "10.0000", but no, it prints out "0.000000".

I wrestled with this for hours, trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, and then I changed the code in my appDelegate to

```
FloatView *floatView = [[FloatView alloc] init];
[floatView floatTest:10.0f];
```

Only then, did it print out the expected "10.0000". Why is this so? I've declared FloatView as a subclass of UIView, shouldn't I be able to assign a FloatView object to a UIView pointer without problems?

Even though floatView was declared a pointer to a UIView, it's really a floatView and it should be able to handle the floatTest message? Am I totally off base here?

Comment: Your code generated a a compiler warning, right? If you had figured out why, you would have fixed the problem.

Comment: It might have fixed the problem, but I probably wouldn't have understood why it was behaving the way it was. Your comment is really not helpful. My thanks to the Mehrdad Afshari for the detailed response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, polymorphism is working as expected. If it didn't work, nothing would have been printed (in your example, 0.0000 is being printed). The thing is, while your instance actually responds to `testFloat:10.0f` message, since the compiler can't statically see the method declaration (as `UIView` class doesn't declare such a method), it assumes that your method takes `...` as argument and returns `id`.

When `CGFloat` is passed to a method that expects variable number of arguments (`...`), it's promoted to `double`. Thus, the receiving method is passed a `double` argument and thinks it's a `float` and it doesn't get printed correctly.

You can verify this behavior by changing `NSLog` line to:

```
NSLog(@"%f", *(double*)&x);
```

When the compiler sends the message to `FloatView*` rather than a `UIView*`, it can find the exact signature of the method. It can see it really expects `CGFloat` and doesn't promote the argument to `double`. As a result, it works correctly.

Additionally, if `UIView*` contained the method declaration that took a `CGFloat`, the compiler would call the method appropriately. To summarize, this is not a polymorphism issue; it's a missing method signature issue.